# How long can a US green card holder spend outside the US?

Tags: usa, multiple-entry, us-residents

I am an American green card holder - after living for 2.5 months in the USA, I came to Afghanistan for a family illness and returned back to the US after 6 months. Can I come back for 5 months again?

Is there any legal implication on my green card status?

Comment: Having a green card means you are required to live permanently in the US. If you do not intend to live in the US you can have your green card revoked.

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference but do you own or rent a home in the US that you will maintain during your absence?

Comment: I think that is more of an [Expats.SE] question.

Comment: It should be fine.